# Android detect marked word

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-theme

i want to make app than when you long press on a word(and it marked) it put on the sceen a button, and if you press the button a new theme (small window) would show the word(marked word).  Now my question is how do I know what word the user marked, does android allow it.  And another question is of course how do I do it?